# How can I combine two "else" into one?

Tags: java, if-statement

In my program I have two similar "else"(return null) and I want to combine them

```
public Task taskFromString(String taskString) {
        String[] splitTaskString = taskString.split(",");
        if (splitTaskString.length > 1) {
            if (TypeOfTask.valueOf(splitTaskString[1]) == TypeOfTask.SUBTASK) {
                return new Subtask(splitTaskString[2], splitTaskString[4],
                        Status.valueOf(splitTaskString[3]), TypeOfTask.valueOf(splitTaskString[1]),
                        Integer.parseInt(splitTaskString[5]));
            } else if (TypeOfTask.valueOf(splitTaskString[1]) == TypeOfTask.TASK) {
                return new Task(splitTaskString[2], splitTaskString[4],
                        Status.valueOf(splitTaskString[3]), TypeOfTask.valueOf(splitTaskString[1]));
            } else if (TypeOfTask.valueOf(splitTaskString[1]) == TypeOfTask.EPIC) {
                return new Epic(splitTaskString[2], splitTaskString[4],
                        Status.valueOf(splitTaskString[3]), TypeOfTask.valueOf(splitTaskString[1]));
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The only thing that comes to mind is to combine them in the first "if" using logical operations, but I'm not sure that this is the most optimal way

Answer (score 5):

**Remove** both and fall-through. Like,

```
String[] splitTaskString = taskString.split(",");
if (splitTaskString.length > 1) {
    if (TypeOfTask.valueOf(splitTaskString[1]) == TypeOfTask.SUBTASK) {
        return new Subtask(splitTaskString[2], splitTaskString[4],
                Status.valueOf(splitTaskString[3]), TypeOfTask.valueOf(splitTaskString[1]),
                Integer.parseInt(splitTaskString[5]));
    } else if (TypeOfTask.valueOf(splitTaskString[1]) == TypeOfTask.TASK) {
        return new Task(splitTaskString[2], splitTaskString[4],
                Status.valueOf(splitTaskString[3]), TypeOfTask.valueOf(splitTaskString[1]));
    } else if (TypeOfTask.valueOf(splitTaskString[1]) == TypeOfTask.EPIC) {
        return new Epic(splitTaskString[2], splitTaskString[4],
                Status.valueOf(splitTaskString[3]), TypeOfTask.valueOf(splitTaskString[1]));
    }
}
return null;
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need either of them.  Just drop the `else` blocks and make `return null;` the default action at the end of the method if no other action was taken:

```
public Task taskFromString(String taskString) {
    String[] splitTaskString = taskString.split(",");
    if (splitTaskString.length > 1) {
        if (TypeOfTask.valueOf(splitTaskString[1]) == TypeOfTask.SUBTASK) {
            return new Subtask(splitTaskString[2], splitTaskString[4],
                    Status.valueOf(splitTaskString[3]), TypeOfTask.valueOf(splitTaskString[1]),
                    Integer.parseInt(splitTaskString[5]));
        } else if (TypeOfTask.valueOf(splitTaskString[1]) == TypeOfTask.TASK) {
            return new Task(splitTaskString[2], splitTaskString[4],
                    Status.valueOf(splitTaskString[3]), TypeOfTask.valueOf(splitTaskString[1]));
        } else if (TypeOfTask.valueOf(splitTaskString[1]) == TypeOfTask.EPIC) {
            return new Epic(splitTaskString[2], splitTaskString[4],
                    Status.valueOf(splitTaskString[3]), TypeOfTask.valueOf(splitTaskString[1]));
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```